# VS Code terminal font size

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

About a couple of weeks ago, I downloaded course files from a course I'm studying online and the minute i opened the folder in vs code, all other vs code projects' **terminal font size were affected; became so small they can't be readable**. I searched for a solution for a couple of days and I even tried uninstalling vs code then re-installing it, but nothing worked.

I now have to use an external terminal to run any command and it's very frustrating.

If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I apologize for not replying back right away, I've been very busy with work and did not get the chance to check stack overflow.

Answer (score 14):

How about going to the `settings.json` and adding e.g.

```
 "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
```

or what ever you like. You can also go to the gear menu (bottom left) select `Settings`, search for `terminal font size` and then enter the size of your choice.

Comment: I already did, but for some reason it doesn't affect the terminal font size. I have been doing some more searching but I wasn't able to fix the issue. I tried to change the editor font size to make sure that my vs code was working properly and it change right in front of my eyes, but the terminal font size just doesn't seem to be affected.

Answer (score 6):

1. Choose 'Terminal -> New Terminal' from menu bar.
2. There are things I describe on picture below:
   [image]
3. Click on the arrow near name of the shell and choose 'Configure Terminal Settings'.
4. 'Settings' tab will open and you should see two tabs: 'User' and 'Workspace'.
5. In 'Workspace' scroll to "Terminal › Integrated: Font Size" and there you can change size of your font. The same setting is also available in 'User' tab, but in my case changing in 'Workspace' helped.

Comment: When you set font size in 'User' tab it will be available for all your projects, which seems to be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same problem and tried all of the above. If this is the case for you than you might see if the font family has changed or is different. This can be found in the settings as mentioned above. I changed it to the 'Times New Roman' and it worked great. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, then i find there is already a .vscode in the opened folder and i do not have permission to modify setting.json in it. That's why the modifications in vscode UI have not been taking effect. I modified setting.json using sudo, then it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).